# How should I setup the Enzyme Adapter config file with Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I've followed the instructions in other projects and threads but can't make React find the Enzyme config file.

`package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
"jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js, jsx, mjs}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>src/setupTests.js"
    ]
  }
```

`src/setupTests.js`

```
import Enzyme from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
export { shallow, render, mount } from "enzyme";
export { shallowToJson } from "enzyme-to-json";

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

export default Enzyme;
```

`the error when running tests`

```
Enzyme Internal Error: Enzyme expects an adapter to be configured, but found none.
To configure an adapter, you should call `Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })`
before using any of Enzyme's top level APIs, where `Adapter` is the adapter
corresponding to the library currently being tested. For example:

import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15';
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow by this configuraion:

```
// test-setup.js
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

then add a `setupFilesAfterEnv` key in your jest configuration and point to that file. For example, if your jest configuration is in `package.json`:

```
// package.json
{
  "jest": {
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>src/setupTests.js"]
  }
}
```

from the enzyme docs: 
https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/jest.html

> A list of paths to modules that run some code to configure or set up
>   the testing framework before each test. Since setupFiles executes
>   before the test framework is installed in the environment, this script
>   file presents you the opportunity of running some code immediately
>   after the test framework has been installed in the environment.

Comment: i set mine up like this but it's giving me an error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token {" . i think because i'm using typescript. how do you set that up?

Comment: Today file ```setupTests.js``` loads automatically. So, we can forget about adding ```setupFilesAfterEnv``` into the ```package.json```

Answer (score 0):

Add `setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>src/setupTests.js']` in jest.config.js and it will work fine